# Auto-populate column with data from another list based on another column choice

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, auto-populate

I have two lists (Suppliers and PO's). When someone fills out the PO form I want the Supplier ID column to auto-populate based on the chosen Supplier Name. I tried using a lookup column but the Suppliers list has over 15K lines so this does not work. I've spent all day trying to find a solution online but have failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.